# Calculating the confidence interval of a curve fitted through data points each with a confidence interval itself

Tags: confidence-interval, curve-fitting

I have a number of data points, (x,y), where both variables represents a measured quantity each with a confidence interval. These variables correlate strongly with each other.

I want to fit a curve through these points and find the confidence interval of the fitted parameters allowing me to measure one quantity and calculate the other, within a confidence interval.

How do i calculate the confidence interval of the fitted parameters, taking **both** the residuals and the confidence interval of the data points into consideration?

Given my goal, is this the best approach to reaching it? Are the any other solutions?

Comment: What kind of data are they? Eg, are they continuous values, or proportions, etc?

Comment: Both variables are continuous values.

Comment: One issue: If both variables have error, you will need to take account of that in the modelling; standard regression methods will be biased.

Comment: Glen_b, thank you. I was barking up the wrong tree. That comment was enough to nudge me in the right direction.

I'll read up on error-in-variables models and methods for calculating the confidence region.

edit: How do I mark my post as answered, if your comment answered it?